# Windows forms application publishing error on client's PC

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server-2008

I made a windows forms application with c# and connected it to *SQL Server 2008 R2 Database* and published it.

But,whenever i try to install it using SQL Express it gets me Error 40.

I've uninstalled **SQL Express** from the client's PC and installed *SQL Server 2008 R2 Express*.

But it gets me error "**Login failed for user''**".

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Can give us any more details about the error - the exact text, title etc

Comment: You have to fix the `connection string `

Comment: Is there a firewall preventing the connection?

Comment: No, there's no firewall.

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like your connection to the SQL Server is the issue either because the service is not running, the user your are trying to login as is not authenticated or not setup or there is just something wrong with the connection string (The format is different sometimes) http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: The fact you get "login failed" suggests that it is at least getting the SQL Server

Comment: This is the connection string which I use: @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=" + Application.StartupPath + @"\myDB.mdf;Integrated security = true"

Comment: How does the connection string look as one complete string, after pulling in Application.StartupPath?

Comment: Did this help you get to an answer?

Comment: Sorry for being late to reply.This is the path. D:\Boda's Private\My VS Projects\ClothesShop\ClothesShop\bin\Debug